# Add right/left border to UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, ios7, uikit

I'm in the process of customizing my UITabBarItems on my tabbar. I was wondering if there was a property on these items to add right/left borders like below.

[image: borders!]

I found an article to do something similar [here](http://felipecypriano.com/2012/02/27/how-to-customize-uitabbar-on-ios-5/) (blog post about adding a full-width background image on the tab bar), but it looks like scaling that image to fit on all device sizes might get ugly. Can someone point me in the right direction on the proper way to do this?

Comment: as I know there is no such property, you need to create custom views. Or just simply add separator views (lines) to your tab bar by programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create Custom Tabbar.

Below link have many customized tabbar examples. I hope it will help for you.

[Custom tab Bar URL](http://code4app.net/category/tabbar)